# how to unbind document.ondblclick with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Some Web**

```
<SCRIPT SRC="js/tt2.js"></SCRIPT>
```

**tt2.js**

```
toggle=0;
function dblclick() {
    if (toggle==0) {
        var sc=99999; toggle=1;
    } else {
        var sc=0; toggle=0;
    }
    window.scrollTo(0,sc);
}
if (document.layers) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.ONDBLCLICK);
}
document.ondblclick=dblclick;
```

"document.ondblclick = null;" is dosen't work.
how can i remove(unbind) dblclick event with chrome extension?

Comment: How you tried `document.ondblclick = function () {}`. Also, you should really use `.addEventListener` so you can use the appropriate `.removeEventListener`.

Comment: thank you for answer. but that code dosen't work too.
and the site isn't mine. so i can't modifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

You are able to override `document.ondblclick`. Problem is the context. You have chrome-extension context and page-context.

[image: possible context]

For testing you can add in your extension follows:

```
document.ondblclick = function () {
    alert("chrome extension ondblclick event");
}
```

You can take a look in both contexts the event:

[image: event callbacks on each context]

If you fire this event you will see that both events are called.

**Solution:**

What you need is to override `ondblclick` in page-context. Really easy way to do this is add your own script into page - then it will run in page-context.

To inject script you can write `inject.js`:

```
(function(){
    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    scriptElement.setAttribute('src', chrome.runtime.getURL('js/ownOndblclick.js'));

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
}());
```

And you need script that you have to inject. In this case this is `ownOndblclick.js`:

```
document.ondblclick = function () {
    alert("free");
}
```

alert is just for testing. Remove it after you see that it works like expected.
Last step is to adjust `manifest.json`:

```
{
    ...

    "permissions": [
        "http://whereever/*"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://whereever/*"],
            "js": ["js/inject.js"]
        }
    ],

    "web_accessible_resources" : [
        "js/ownOndblclick.js"
    ]
}
```

That's it.

Alternative to inject `ownOndblclick.js` is to put it directly into `inject.js`:

```
(function(){
    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    scriptElement.innerText = 'document.ondblclick = function () { alert("free");}';

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
}());
```

Then you can remove `web_accessible_resources` from `manifest.json`.

Comment: Thanks. Issue has been resolved.
I solved before view answer, but is similar.

Comment: You, sir, saved my day after hours and hours of searching!! I was trying to unbind a "onbeforeunload" event using an extension and tried a million of options, but only this one worked. Thank you!